# deleting the common parts of two images

Tags: python, opencv

Say I have the following two images:

before.png:

[image]

after.png:

[image]

I'd like to remove all the parts of after.png that are in before.png so that, unto the end, I have this:

[image]

. My question is...  how can I do this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import cv2

refFilename = 'before.png'
newFilename = 'after.png'
outFilename = 'output.png'

imRef = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
th, imBW = cv2.threshold(imRef, 128, 192, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

imNew = cv2.imread(newFilename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(imNew, imNew, imBW)

cv2.imwrite(outFilename, result)
```

The output, however, looks just like after.png. I also tried passing `cv2.bitwise_not(imBW)` to `cv2.bitwise_and` instead of `imBW` but that made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try "bitwise_xor" but this will also make the background black.

Comment: You could read each into a numpy array and loop over each pixel.

Comment: Please, define what exactly you mean by "remove" -- how exactly should the result look like for those particular inputs? (maybe provide illustration) Then generalize that definition -- what would it look like if the inputs were inverse (white circle and text, black background)? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the two images as grayscale
- Convert to binary by Otsu thresholding
- Invert the two binary images
- Get the absolute difference
- Invert the difference
- Save results

Input:

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2

# read the two images
img1 = cv2.imread('circle1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('circle2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to binary
bin1 = cv2.threshold(img1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
bin2 = cv2.threshold(img2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert each
bin1 = 255 - bin1
bin2 = 255 - bin2

# get absdiff
diff = cv2.absdiff(bin2, bin1)

# invert
diff = 255 - diff

# save result
cv2.imwrite('circles_diff.jpg', diff)

# show result
cv2.imshow('diff',diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Resulting difference:

[image]

**ADDITION**

To answer your question in your comment, change cv2.absdiff to cv2.subtract.

Image:

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2

# read the two images
img1 = cv2.imread('circle3.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('circle2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to binary
bin1 = cv2.threshold(img1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
bin2 = cv2.threshold(img2, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert each
bin1 = 255 - bin1
bin2 = 255 - bin2

# get absdiff
diff = cv2.subtract(bin2, bin1)

# invert
diff = 255 - diff

# save result
cv2.imwrite('circles_diff2[![enter image description here][6]][6].jpg', diff)

# show result
cv2.imshow('diff',diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So this solution is kinda doing an XOR on the two images. If a pixel is black in one but white in the other it's set to black in this one. Using this approach the order of the images doesn't matter. But what if I wanted to get the same result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ7uV.jpg) by removing everything in (A) https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LdFy.jpg from (B) https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnZk0.jpg ? Like I don't want to add stuff from A to B - I just want to remove stuff in A from B.